# Android Wear: Programmatically stop my app's notifications from appearing on watch

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

From reading about [wearable-notifications documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html), it doesn't seem possible to programmatically stop my app's notifications from appearing on the connected wearable device. I can add an my app to 'muted' apps' list using the Android Wear app on the handheld; however, I would like to do this using code. Please let me know if you've figured this out.

Additionally, is it possible to show a completely different notification on the phone and on the wearable, instead of just having a different set of notification actions on the wearable?

Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First question:

I'm afraid muting apps from code is not possible.

### Second question:

It is possible to show different notifications on phone and watch.
You can do it by implementing a wearable application and show local (`setLocalOnly()`) notifications separately on watch and phone (+ sync them with the phone using `DataApi`).

Alternatively you can make use of group feature of Android Wear framework. It's basically created to post many (grouped) notifications on wearable device and one summary notification on phone. But using this mechanism you can also post one (summary) notification on your phone and second notification only on wear.

```
final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// This notification will be shown only on phone
final NotificationCompat.Builder phoneNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Title phone")
    .setContentText("Text phone")
    .setGroup("GROUP")
    .setGroupSummary(true);

// This notification will be shown only on watch
final NotificationCompat.Builder wearableNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Title wearable")
    .setContentText("Text wearable")
    .setGroup("GROUP")
    .setGroupSummary(false);

notificationManager.notify(0, phoneNotificationBuilder.build());
notificationManager.notify(1, wearableNotificationBuilder.build());
```

This way you can create "stack" with one notification only (+ summary notification of course). The stack with one notification will appear only on watch and the summary notification will appear only on phone - so this is what you want to achieve:)

Please read more about grouping (stacking) notifications here:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: If I go for the 'wearable app and setLocalOnly()' approach, would I see two notifications on the wearable; one from the wearable app and another auto-displayed by Android?

Comment: Your phone app also need to display notification with `setLocalOnly()`

Comment: Perfect. Let me try this out too. :)

Comment: Thanks! setLocalOnly() can be used to control whether to display a notification on the phone, or on the phone and on the connected wearable.

Answer (score 8):

Using [`setLocalOnly(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean)), it is possible to display the notification only on phone. This, in effect, programmatically mutes your app - your app's notifications do not appear on the connected devices.

To create completely different notifications for phone and wearable, we can write a companion wearable app that displays the custom notification. The phone notification is then stopped from appearing on wearable using `setLocalOnly()`. I haven't tried the 'stacking' mentioned by Maciej Ciemięga yet.

(Added this as an answer for the benefit of those who might miss the comments on the accepted answer.)